# Counting values from range object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, range

I have a quiz. with 5 question, each with sliders ranging from a value of 0 to 5.
I want to end the quiz with your total points scored. How can i acces the values in javascript and add them together.

Here is one question,

```
<form class="questionForm-1" id="q1" data-question="1">
    <div id="qhead" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
        <h1>Question 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="ondertitel" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
        <h2>Ik ervaar rust wanneer ik een duidelijke planning heb voor die dag. </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="form-check" id="form-check">
        <div class="d-flex p-4 text-center">
            <label for="customRange2" class="form-label">Example range</label>
            <input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="5" id="input1"
                oninput="q1points.value = this.value">
            <output id="q1points">0</output>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="res_1"></p>
    <button id="btn-1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Volgende</button>
</form>
```

i use `oninput="q1points.value = this.value"> <output id="q1points">0</output>`
to display the Values, but it is done in HTML,

so how can i acces these values and count them together?
(each question has an output id of : q1points, q2points, q3points, q4points, q5points)

Thank you so much,

EDIT : i have setup a button for debugging/ going to next question.
where can i see my value of the range input now? @akirus

```
$('#btn-1').click(function () {
    console.log(result);
    $('#q1').hide();
    $('#q2').show();
```

COMPLETE CODES

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //$('#results').hide();
    $('#q2,#q3,#q4,#q5').hide();
    $('#q1').show();

    $('#emailform').hide();

    $('#btn-1').click(function () {
        $('#q1').hide();
        console.log("input1");
        $('#q2').show();
    });

    $('#btn-2').click(function () {
        $('#q2').hide();
        $('#q3').show();
    });

    $('#btn-3').click(function () {
        $('#q3').hide();
        $('#q4').show();
    });

    $('#btn-4').click(function () {
        $('#q4').hide();
        $('#q5').show();
    });

    $('#btn-5').click(function () {
        $('#q5').hide();
        $('#results').show();
    });



});

// initialise a counter
document.getElementById('btn-5').addEventListener('click', () => {
    let result = 0; 

 // list of range input ids
    const ranges = ['input1', 'input2', 'input3', 'input4', 'input5'];
   
// parse int so value is a number
    ranges.forEach((range) => {
        const rangeVal = parseInt(document.getElementById(range).value);

        console.log(rangeVal); // log value
        results += rangeVal; // add value to counter
    });

    console.log(results); // log result
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = results; // show value
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- QUESTION 1  -->
    <form class="questionForm-1" id="q1" data-question="1">
        <div id="qhead" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h1>Question 1</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="ondertitel" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h2>Ik ervaar rust wanneer ik een duidelijke planning heb voor die dag. </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check" id="form-check">
            <div class="d-flex p-4 text-center">
                <label for="customRange2" class="form-label">Example range</label>
                <input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="5" id="input1"
                    oninput="q1points.value = this.value">
                <output id="q1points">0</output>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id="res_1"></p>
        <button id="btn-1" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Volgende</button>
    </form>



    <!-- QUESTION 2  -->
    <form class="questionForm-2" id="q2" data-question="2">
        <div id="qhead" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h1>Question 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="ondertitel" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h2>Ik ben bezig met de manier waarop ik in het leven sta en neem de tijd om hierop te reflecteren. </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check" id="form-check">
            <div class="d-flex p-4 text-center">
                <label for="customRange2" class="form-label">Example range</label>
                <input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="5" id="input2"
                    oninput="q2points.value = this.value">
                <output id="q2points">0</output>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id="res_2"></p>
        <button id="btn-2" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Volgende</button>
    </form>

    <!-- QUESTION 3  -->

    <form class="questionForm-3" id="q3" data-question="3">
        <div id="qhead" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h1>Question 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="ondertitel" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h2>Houdt jij vaak rekening met de impact en afkomst van de producten die je koopt/eet?</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check" id="form-check">
            <div class="d-flex p-4 text-center">
                <label for="customRange2" class="form-label">Example range</label>
                <input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="5" id="input3"
                    oninput="q3points.value = this.value">
                <output id="q3points">0</output>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        <p id="res_3"></p>
        <button id="btn-3" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Volgende</button>
    </form>

    <!-- QUESTION 4  -->

    <form class="questionForm-4" id="q4" data-question="4">
        <div id="qhead" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h1>Question 4</h1>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ondertitel" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h2>Ik ga ver om tijd vrij te maken om anderen te helpen? </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check" id="form-check">
            <div class="d-flex p-4 text-center">
                <label for="customRange2" class="form-label">Example range</label>
                <input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="5" id="input4"
                    oninput="q4points.value = this.value">
                <output id="q4points">0</output>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
        <p id="res_4"></p>
        <button id="btn-4" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Volgende</button>
    </form>

    <!-- QUESTION 5  -->

    <form class="questionForm-5" id="q5" data-question="5">
        <div id="qhead" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h1>Question 5</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="ondertitel" class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight text-center">
            <h2>Ik sta voor wat ik vind en wil die mening of opvatting ook graag delen met anderen.</h2>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check" id="form-check">
            <div class="d-flex p-4 text-center">
                <label for="customRange2" class="form-label">Example range</label>
                <input type="range" class="form-range" min="0" max="5" id="input5"
                    oninput="q5points.value = this.value">
                <output id="q5points">0</output>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p id="res_5"></p>

        <div class="d-flex">
            <button id="btn-5" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Resultaten</button>
            <!-- <button id="btn-6" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">opnieuw</button> -->
        </div>

    </form>
    <div id="group"></div>
    <p id="result"></p>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="quiz_2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You cannot ping specific users (using `@username`) in a question; @ mentions only work in comments. Also, adding questions to your question when your question has been answered is considered bad form on Stack Overflow. Ask a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I retrieve and display slider range value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103818/how-can-i-retrieve-and-display-slider-range-value)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the value of a range input:

```
document.getElementById('input1').value
```

Then you just need to iterate through all your inputs and add the values to some `counter` variable.

Edit: [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-hdwuuv?file=index.js)

Comment: Thank you so much, so what i take from this i need to use the ID of the range object and not the ID of the output? (i see u used input1 instead of q1points in ur example)

Comment: Also, can i use  document.write('input1'); so i can display if it works? (for debugging purposes)

Comment: In theory you could do document.getElementById('q1points').value as well, but that would return you a string value so it would add an extra step of having to parseInt(theValue) to use it's value as a number.


document.write('input1'); would basically replace your entire html with the text 'input1'. For debugging you could do a button that on click does the math and have a console.log(result) or more logs through the function to make sure everything works as expected.

Comment: i have edited my question, to imply the console.log(result) but where can i see my result? is this in the chrome console?

Comment: Aye, the console.log() outputs to the chrome console

Comment: how can i setup a variable for results? is it var results = #input1;

Comment: Added a working example to the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! i'm gonna study this thing closely. U really made my day !

Comment: Hey @akirus i can't seem to run the file offline, when i download it. do i miss some config on the JSON files?

Comment: That is a general example so you probably need to adapt it for your code.

If your requirement is to show range2 after an action happens on range1 then you need to keep the counter outside of the function and add the value of a range to it within the event listener for that range.

Comment: add <script src="index.js"></script> to end of the html file
remove import './style.css'; from js file and it should work

Comment: I want the "score" to be placed after button; "btn-5", i'm good with all calculations happening once you click that button. so i have placed the whole snippet after that ( see edited code on post ).

Comment: Looks fine. I think if you change the id's in the snippet to match your code it should work just fine

Comment: I think i have? i changed the snippet of code to use you send to look for the ID's "input1",input2,input3,input4,input5" in the HTML but after btn-5 click i still have a blank screen, do u know what's wrong? im sorry, i'm new to java! (my complete HTML/JAVA are updated in my post

Comment: <p id="result"></p>
but in the code you're setting the value on results
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = results; // show value

also it's javascript not java :)

Comment: Thank you! i changed all of it to "result" and it works ! you are a legend man !